# ruby a = b || c if b is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

Working with a large dataset. Generally the data is good but for a few entries a value is missing.

I want my seed to:

```
player.nationality = dataset_row.player_nationality or 'US' if dataset_row.player_nationality is undefined
```

Also, looking for a one-liner solution.  thanks!

Comment: `a = b.present? ? b : c`

Comment: @gabrielhilal `presence` is much cleaner for this construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
player.nationality = dataset_row.player_nationality.presence || 'US'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can however use `.presence` to account for `nil` _and_ the empty string.

Comment: That's correct, I used `try` to avoid nilClass error in case dataset_row comes blank, but use of presence makes sense here, thank you! I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
player.nationality = dataset_row.player_nationality.present? ? dataset_row.player_nationality : 'US'
```

Comment: `presence` is a lot nicer for this use.